# Action buttons in Firebase Notification using python?

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want two action buttons in my notification: Receive & Decline
and their click action to hit different APIs. I am using python, flutter & firebase to send notifications to device. I am able to send simple-text notification and it is working fine.
Here's my script to send simple notification:

```
import requests
import json

def SendCallNotification():
    try:
        server_token = 'my server token'
        device_token = 'my device token'
    except:
        return False
    
    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'key=' + server_token,
    }

    body = {
        'notification': {
            'title': 'Sending push from Python script',
            'body': 'New Message',
            'click_action': 'https://exampleapi.com/api/v1/', 
            
        },
        'to': device_token,
        'priority': 'high',
    }

    response = requests.post("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send", headers=headers, data=json.dumps(body))
    print(response.status_code)
    print(response.json())

SendCallNotification()
```

I tried changing the body context to:

```
body = {
    "to": deviceToken,
    "priority": "high",
    "data": {
        "title": "Sending push from python script",
        "body": "New Message",
        "buttons": {
            "button1": "Decline",
            "button2": "Receive"
        }
    }
}
```

but it didn't even sent a notification but response was success.

I expected notification with two action buttons...

Thank You.